# How to install Debian package with file extension .deb

Tags: debian

I am trying to install a Debian package, but it gives error as "sudo: dpkg: command not found".
I installed SUDO, and it still giving the same error.
I went to the dir where .deb is saved, and ran command as

```
sudo dkpg -i file.deb
```

I tried installing the debian support package from "http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/dpkg-dev/download", but these files also are in .deb format, so I am unable to install this.

Any suggestions...

Comment: "dpkg: command not found" - it means that there is no `dpkg` command not `sudo` command. What distro are you using? Is it really Debian? What version? How you installed `sudo`?

Comment: You are misspelling `dpkg` in your example command. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Can you post the output of `lsb_release -a`?

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out in the comments, if that's an exact quote of what you're typing to try to install it you're making a typo:

```
sudo dkpg -i file.deb
```

won't work, but

```
sudo dpkg -i file.deb
```

will.

Spelling is not optional when it comes to the command line.

Answer (score 4):

Try them :

Method 1)
Right-click on the *deb file, and open it with `gdebi`. This will install any needed dependencies for you.

Method 2)
 
You need to specify where is the file is. E.g.:

```
sudo dpkg -i Desktop/install_flash_player_10_linux.deb
```

Method 3)
The error can also occur when your shell cannot find `sudo`.

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

Almost certainly, `sudo` needs to be installed. Login as root and run:

```
# apt-get install sudo
```

An error is also given when you are trying to install many debian files simultaneously.
First let one file install completely through Software center and then try using the command.

Comment: Method 2): if `dpkg` cannot be found, specifying the full path will not help at all. Method 3): the OP already tried that.